# Graphlets in python

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to calculate the graphlet degree (basically the count of graphlets rooted at a node) for each node in a graph in python. I am using networkx library and am unable to find a suitable implementation. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Please define graphlet in a comprehensible way.  Wikipedia is gobbledygook

Comment: Also, you say you want to calculate  "the graphlet degree *vector*" which you define as "the *count* of graphlets"  But, a count cannot be a vector!  Please be more careful about terminology, especially for such a brief question with no examples, no code, or any real details at all.

Comment: The FGLT package (https://github.com/fcdimitr/fglt) does have Python wrappers (disclaimer: I am a maintainer). We also plan to publish a corresponding Python package, similarly to the Julia package (https://github.com/nsailor/FastGraphletTransform.jl)